# How do I check if items already exist in a ToolStripMenuItem DropDownItems?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
items = File
    .ReadLines(RecentFiles)
    .Select(line => new ToolStripMenuItem()
    {
        Text = line
    })
    .ToArray();
recentFilesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(items);
```

I want to check if the items exist already in the `recentFilesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems`

If not exist add but if exist don't add.

Comment: Are you sure you don't simply want to clear it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically have two collections: `items` & `recentFilesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems`

Using `Linq`, you should be able to do <del>an `Except()`</del> a `Where()` to only add the difference between the two collections.

This is not tested.

<del>recentFilesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.AddRange(items.Except(recentFilesToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems));</del>

This is tested

```
recentFilesToolStrip.DropDownItems.AddRange(
    items
    .Where(i => !recentFilesToolStrip.DropDownItems
                 .OfType<ToolStripMenuItem>()
                 .Select(t => t.Text).Contains(i.Text)
          ).ToArray()
);
```

SLaks comment refers to doing something like the following:

```
recentFilesToolStripMenuItems.DropDownItems.Clear();
recentFilesToolStripMenuItems.DropDownItems.AddRange(items);
```

Comment: Shar im getting errors on this: Error 2 Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemCollection' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem>'

Comment: Error 4 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem>' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemCollection'

Comment: Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem[]' does not contain a definition for 'Except' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Except<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Error 3 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemCollection.AddRange(System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItemCollection)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @SimonGamlieli Apologies, as I did note that the code was not tested.  Updated answer does work.